# Type-Casting one User Defined Object to Another

Tags: c++

I have modified both the user defined classes to have constructors that accepts an object of the other class as it's argument.

**Does this cover all the bases or do I have to overload the assignment operator and the type-cast operator as well to handle all the implicit and explicit type casting cases?**

Eg:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Celsius; // Forward Declaration

class Fahrenheit {
    double temp;
public:
    Fahrenheit(double d = 0.0) : temp(d) {}
    Fahrenheit(Celsius);
    void setTemp(double d) { temp = d; }
    double getTemp() { return temp; }
    void print() { cout << "\nThe temperature value in Fahrenheit is " << temp << endl; }
};

class Celsius {
    double temp;
public:
    Celsius(double d = 0.0) : temp(d) {}
    Celsius(Fahrenheit f) { temp = ((f.getTemp()-32) * 5) / 9; }
    void setTemp(double d) { temp = d; }
    double getTemp() { return temp; }
    void print() { cout << "\nThe temperature value in Celsius is " << temp << endl; }
};

Fahrenheit::Fahrenheit(Celsius c) { temp = ((c.getTemp() * 9) / 5) + 32; }

int main() {
    Fahrenheit t1(20);
    Celsius t2(t1);
    Fahrenheit t3(50);
    t2.print();
    t2 = (Celsius) t3;
    t2.print();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think all the type-casting cases work by just having the appropriate constructors. So, I **don't need to overload the assignment and typecast operators at all**, right?

Comment: Personally I would have a Temperature class, which stores it in any suitable fashion, and ToCelsius and ToFahrenheit functions, returning the number values.

Comment: @NeilKirk: I see, but still...I'm looking to see how typecasting between two user-defined objects works.

Comment: I can't see any pitfalls, but I didn't put as an answer as I'm not super certain about it.